# Power Bank Recommendation

Tags: smartphones, power-bank

I use my Google Nexus 6P to take some HDR+ photos while travelling, and it drains considerable battery power. I am looking for a power bank probably 20000 mAh or more. But I am not aware of any particular one that charges my phone "rapidly" similar to power adaptor using USB Type C port. It would be great If I could charge the power bank itself rapidly as well.

Can any one please suggest any power bank to me?

Comment: Finally zeroed in on Anker powecor+ 20100. It seems to deliver what I wanted

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Portable-Charger-PowerPack-Ultra-High-Density/dp/B01BLXY3B6/ref=sr_1_74?ie=UTF8&qid=1485835046&sr=8-74&keywords=usb+power+bank&refinements=p_72%3A2661618011

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Qi-infinity8482-50000mAH-External-Battery-Charger/dp/B01C6476CW